# Joining tables in MYSQL without a common column

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

I have searched the answers on how to join two tables in MYSQL without a common column on internet but did not find what I was looking out exactly. So I have two tables as shown below.

TABLE userDetails

```
id empID   Name
1   001    Rhonda
```

TABLE request

```
id ticketNo  Details
1  00000123  {"userDetails":{"id":"1", "empID":"001", "Name":"Rhonda"}
```

Now what I want to do is I want to  write a query that when I search for empId:001 I want that the table returns me with that ticket number for that particular EMPID. But the problem here is that there are no common columns and second that the details of that user in Table Request is under column **details**. I am stuck as to how to achieve this. If anyone could help out it would be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `->>` operator within the JOIN condition after fixing the JSON column format such as
converting it to the form `{"userDetails":{"id":"1", "empID":"001", "Name":"Rhonda"}}` :

```
SELECT ticketNo 
  FROM request r
  JOIN userDetails u
    ON r.Details ->> '$.userDetails.empID' = u.empID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c50e489297d0681ff0cbd5a8b75aff8c)</kbd>

**Update** : Perhaps, you can try to replace `u.empID` with `CONVERT(u.empID USING utf8)` or `CONVERT(u.empID USING latin1)` in order to catch the proper collation

Comment: Hi, My bad that in the post I did not mention but Json column format is {"userDetails":{"id":"1", "empID":"001", "Name":"Rhonda"} already. Also I tried your solution but it throws me error. ERROR IS: Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_bin,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Comment: you're welcome @Alisa . The $ sign means to start the search at the top level of the JSON document, where dots represent steps for each keys. You can [refer](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) .

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working perfectly fine now!! @Barbaros